# Convert XML Sitemap into HTML Sitemap, HOW?

Tags: xml, xslt, sitemap

I have a sitemap in XML Format, but it renders as tags.  Do I have to code in a stylesheet, or is there an online solution for plugging in the Sitemap.xml file url into another url that will render it like an HTML Site Map?

Am really in need of this, preferrably, would be great if it could be rendered by group of URLs...

For example, something like this:

```
Path:  http://mydomain.com/folder

http://mydomain.com/folder/index.html
http://mydomain.com/folder/page1.html
http://mydomain.com/folder/page2.html
```

And so on for each URL Path.

Is there something out there that can do something like this?

For example a site that offers this might have a url as follows:
http://sitethatcandothis.com/sitemapurl=http://mydomain.com/sitemap.xml

Or is there another alternative for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GSiteCrawler](http://gsitecrawler.com/en/download/) which which is a spider that will crawl your site and create a sitemap for you.

If you want to do more than generate just a simple sitemap file. You can get a urllist-file for Yahoo, an RSS feed, a ROR file or a HTML sitemap page!

Comment: It appears the tool is now [based here](http://gsitecrawler.com/), but it was last updated in 2007.